# Pointers and arrays in c++ also changing elements

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to code a program for college, that:

1. First, outputs an array of the alphabet, I got that;
2. Then, it is supposed to prompt the user to select a number correlating with a letter of the alphabet within the array, I got that though it actually selects the index number;
3. Next, I am trying to code an output that will output the alphabet with every other letter being 'x', i.e. `A x C x E x G x I x..........`, but with what I have I get `A x x x x x x x x x......`
4. Lastly the program is supposed to prompt the user for selection of the letters as either `A C E G I........` or `B D F H J............`; when I execute that it seems to be an infinite loop of computer language.

Any help is appreciated. This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int i = 0;
const int size = 27;
char newline = '\n';
char *pnumber = 0;
int selection = 0;

int main()
{
    cout << "PRINGING CONTENTS OF ARRAY" << endl;
    cout << "====================================================" << endl;
    char alphabet[size] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'
        , 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0 };

    for (int column = 0; column < size; column++) {
        cout << alphabet[column] << " ";
    }
    {
        cout << newline;
        cout << newline;

        cout << "This is the title to your Program related to the alphabet."
            << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Select the index that coincides with the alphabet."
            << endl;
        cout << "For example, the number 6 should display the letter G"
            << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 25: ";
        cin >> i;
        cout << "The number you selected: " << i;
        cout << newline;
        cout << "The letter related to this number: " << alphabet[i];
        cout << endl; }
        {
            cout << newline;
            cout << newline;
            cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY and adding x to every other element"
            char alphabet[size] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'
                , 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0 };
            char* pnumber(nullptr);
            pnumber = &alphabet[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(alphabet); ++i) {
                *(pnumber + i) = 'x';
            }

            cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    {
        cout << newline;
        cout << newline;
        cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY USING THE MOD Option" << endl;
        cout << "=========================================================
        char alphabet[size] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'
            , 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0 };
        cout << "Do you want the letters of the alphabet starting from index
            0, A, or index 1, B: ";
        cin >> selection;
        if (selection = 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i + 2) {
                cout << alphabet[27] << " ";
            }
        else
            for (int i = 1; i < size; i + 2) {
                cout << alphabet[27] << " ";
            }
        return 0;
    }
} //End of Int Main
```

Comment: that example doesn't even compile

Comment: You redefine `alphabet` twice??

Comment: Why do you expect the second part of your code to print A x C x E x G x ...?

Comment: Why are you outputting `alphabet[27]` all over the place?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The loop with `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(alphabet); ++i) {` writes off the end of the array

Comment: `cout << alphabet[27]` reads past the end of the array (since size is 27, the valid indices are `0` through `26`) - you probably meant `alphabet[i]` here

Comment: So I should only define the array once? I thought it was necessary to redefine. I expect the third part of the code to output A x C x E x.......... The second part is supposed to output the letter associated with the number it is in the alphabet

Comment: Yes, declaration is always once. Never redeclare. You can create new arrays for different outputs.

Comment: Please fix the compilation errors and condense your work into a minimal reproducer.

Comment: When I try to remove the declaration the program throws an error. Should I just declare it globally?

Comment: The program compiles for me. I don't why it isn't elsewhere. I don't know what a minimal reproducer is.

Comment: I have now declared the array globally and taken all redefinitions out

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

int i = 0;
const int size = 27;
char newline = '\n';
char *pnumber = 0;
int selection = 0;


cout << "PRINGING CONTENTS OF ARRAY" << endl;
cout << "====================================================" << endl;

char alphabet[size] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
                        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0 };

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
    }

cout << newline;
cout << newline;

cout << "This is the title to your Program related to the alphabet." << endl;
cout << endl;

cout << "Select the index that coincides with the alphabet." << endl;
cout << "For example, the number 6 should display the letter G" << endl;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter an index between 0 and 25: ";
cin >> i;
cout << "The number you selected: " << i;

cout << newline;
cout << "The letter at this index: " << alphabet[i];
cout << endl;

cout << newline;
cout << newline;

cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY and adding x to every other element" << endl;

pnumber = &alphabet[1];

for (i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "x ";
    }
}

cout << newline;
cout << newline;

cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY USING THE MOD Option" << endl;
cout << "=========================================================" << endl;

cout << "Do you want the letters of the alphabet starting from index 0, A, or index 1, B: ";
cin >> selection;

if (selection = 0)
    for (i = 0; i < size; i += 2) 
    {
        cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
    }
else
    for (i = 1; i < size; i += 2) 
    {
        cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
    }

cout << endl;
cout << endl;
system("pause");
} //End of Int Main
```

I'm not terribly certain where to begin. But here, this runs top-down with the expected behavior as far as I can tell from the original post.

Comment: That is perfect thank you. I had happened upon the modulus from a friend but hadn't leaned the capability in class yet. Is there a way to in the second part have the user choose between 1 and 26 instead of 0 and 25? So that the letters align with their actual position in the alphabet instead of the index?

Comment: I figured out how to do what I wanted that was an ignorant question. But now the issue that I'm running into is here:

Comment: cin >> selection;

        if (selection = 0)
            for (i = 0; i < size; i += 2) 
            {
            cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
            }
        else
           for (i = 1; i < size; i += 2) 
           {
                cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
           }

        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
    } //End of Int Main

Comment: It's the last section, it keeps outputting B D F H J......... but will not start with A

Comment: I can get the program to print either or but not make it through the if statement and print the correct output.

Comment: It is just a simple if statement I don't understand what the issue is

Comment: Do you still need any help with this? Sorry I kind of abandoned it. I can take another look, but only if it will provide you value.

Comment: I'm good thank you, I appreciate your help. Some people are a little gruff.